# Duplicate Total Row Count With Over

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I use "COUNT(*) OVER()" function with SQL Server to get total row count for paging. I use distinct keyword but it's get row count with duplicates rows.

Total row count is 772 normally, but the query returns 1024 because there are duplicate rows.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    ss.ProdSmartId,
    p.ProdId,
    ProdName,
    TotalRowCount = COUNT(*) OVER()
FROM 
    ProdSmartSorts ss
JOIN 
    dbo.Products p ON ss.ProdId = p.ProdId AND p.IsDeleted = 0 AND p.ProdStatus = 1
JOIN 
    Users u ON p.UserId = u.Id
LEFT JOIN 
    Pictures pic ON pic.ProdId = p.ProdId AND pic.IsCover = 1
ORDER BY 
    ss.ProdSmartId 
    OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10000 ROWS ONLY
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `count(*)` doesn't apply to the distinct values returned.

```
declare @table table (i int)
insert into @table
values
(1),
(1),
(1),
(1)

select distinct count(*) over() from @table
```

That's why they are called window functions.  A window function then computes a value for each row in the window. Since you aren't limiting the rows in the window with something like a `partition by` or `row or range` clause, it's going to count all of them. You can use a sub-query though, or other functions. Depends on how you want to handle it.